# Difference between "size" and "itemsize" in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have been studying for numpy library in python.

I used the code

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([(11,12,13),(17,18,19)])
arr.size
```

and it's output is 6

That is right but

when I run

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([(11,12,13),(17,18,19)])
arr.itemsize
```

this code giving me 8 output.

I am not able to understand

Answer (score 1):

[`itemsize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html) has nothing to do with the number of items/dimensions, this is the number of bytes used to store a single item.

Here you have `int64` as dtype:

```
arr=np.array([(11,12,13),(17,18,19)])

arr.dtype
# dtype('int64')
```

Thus the number of bytes used per values is 8.

Another example if you use `int8` as dtype (which allows integers from -127 to 128 and uses a single byte):

```
arr = np.array([(11,12,13),(17,18,19)], dtype='int8')

arr.dtype
# dtype('int8')

arr.itemsize
# 1
```

You can use the product of both values to compute the size of the data in memory (except the metadata, like the shape etc.):

```
arr.itemsize * arr.size
```

Comment: which is `arr.nbytes`